# Extracting xml tags which has a semicolon using SAX in android

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I want to extract attributes from an xml file using Sax Parser

I am able to extract all the tags except those which has a semicolon in it

For example

```
  <geo:lat>-9.9</geo:lat>
```

Whether there is any way to extract date from these tag?
'

Comment: That's a colon, not a semicolon. It means that the element name is a qualified name consisting of a namespace prefix and a local part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geo is predefine parameter,you can directly mach tag in startelement and EndElement method of your SAX parser handler file.
i also face this kind of problem.